# I want to implement paypal integration in my codeigniter code .But What i need is that only one function i.e payment confirmation or verification

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, paypal

I am working with web services on codeigniter framework .My friend working on android app development is using everything of paypal payment gateway as of its own.he asked me to just build one service of paypal that is , payment confirmation or verification. I have uploaded payment library onto my server but i am not getting exact code of payment verification on net.

Comment: If you want to use ci library than use it. https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter

Comment: @AnandPandey , sir i do not want the ci library ,i just want the coding of one function and that is of payment confirmation or verification

Comment: Show your code so far.

Comment: i think you are not understood my answer : )

Answer (score 0):

When you make payment in the paypal you should get the payment_status from the paypal site

Response

```
SUCCESS
mc_gross=1.00
protection_eligibility=Partially+Eligible+-+INR+Only
address_status=unconfirmed
tax=0.00
payment_date=07%3A40%3A51+Aug+06%2C+2013+PDT
payment_status=Completed
charset=windows-1252
first_name=Sureshkumar
etc.....
```

If failed you will get

```
FAIL 403
```

This is used for verify process after transaction id is return.

```
$tx=$_REQUEST['tx'];

$paypal_url='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-synch&tx='.$tx.'&at=token here';
$curl = curl_init($paypal_url);
$data = array(
"cmd" => "_notify-synch",
"tx" => $tx,
"at" => "token here"
);            

$data_string = json_encode($data); 
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);

$headers = array (
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Host: www.paypal.com',
'Connection: close'
);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$lines = explode("\n", $response);
$keyarray = array();
if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {
    for ($i=1; $i<count($lines);$i++){
        list($key,$val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
        $keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
    }
    $first_name=$keyarray['first_name'];
    $last_name=$keyarray['last_name'];
    $payment_status=$keyarray['payment_status'];
    $business=$keyarray['business'];
    $payer_email=$keyarray['payer_email'];
    $payment_gross=$keyarray['payment_gross'];
    $mc_currency=$keyarray['mc_currency']; 
}
```

Comment: If you are not understand anything please feel free to discuss.

Comment: ,sorry to say but yes , i m not getting few things from it.

Comment: So what is you not understand here?